# Why do I get a compilation error upon specifying the return value of an overloaded type?

Tags: c++

I understand that in C++ you can overload an operator like a function. And as common with functions in C++, you have to specify a return value:

```
struct A {

    int operator +();

};
```

Here I've overloaded `operator+` as a function that returns an `int`. But I find that when I overload a type while giving it a return value, I get `error: return type specified for 'operator int'`.

```
struct A {

    void operator int() {} // error

};
```

But if I take away the return value it works fine.

```
struct A {

    operator int() {} // pass

};
```

Does the error mean that by my use of `int` before the function parameters, that I'm creating a function that returns an `int`. Or is this some mistake? What if I want the function to not return a value? Can someone please explain why I'm getting this error? Thanks.

Comment: "What if I want the function to not return at all?" What would such a function even *mean*?

Comment: @GManNickG Suppose the function calls `_exit()` or `abort()` or throws an exception...

Comment: @SegFault: To clarify, I read that as: "What if I want the [operator int] function to not return [a value] at all?" That is a conversion function that returns no value after conversion. (Though there is `operator void`, it cannot be called.)

Comment: @GManNickG Ok, _now_ I understand your initial comment ;-)

Comment: @GManNickG I meant what if I don't want the function to return a value at all. My words weren't chosen wisely as I see now. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By definition, `operator int()` returns an `int`. It will be called in contexts where an object of type `A` needs to be converted to `int`. That's quite different from the first code snippet, where the operator is `operator+()`; you can define it to return pretty much anything you like.

Comment: Yes, the `operator+` is a completely different case.

Answer (score 7):

Well, `operator int` is the operator that turns your A into an `int`, therefore it already has the return type defined, and by writing `void operator int` you are giving it *another* return type!

Answer (score 5):

`operator int()` is implicit conversion operator from your type to `int`. So it could not have any return type except `int` which is defined by operator name.

Answer (score 1):

you're confusing ordinary (unary and binary) operators with *type-conversion* operators